# app returns no error message running Kestrel on nanoserver in Docker (missing dll?)

Tags: docker, asp.net, windows-nano-server

I am trying to run a Kestrel application targeting net461 on Docker, but it fails with no error message.  It runs ok on Windows 10.

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM microsoft/nanoserver
SHELL ["powershell"]
RUN new-item c:\MyAPI -itemtype directory
COPY .\\bin\\Debug\\net461\\win7-x64\\publish MyAPI  
EXPOSE 5000
# ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\MyAPI", "MyAPI.exe"]
```

After publishing I create the image:

```
docker build -t myapi .
```

and run it:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint powershell myapi
```

Then when I start the application manually within the container it stops with no error:

```perl
> cd MyAPI
> .\MyAPI.exe
> $lastExitCode
-1073741515
```

That error code (0xC0000135 or STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND) seems to indicate there's a DLL missing---but how do I figure out what it is on nanoserver if there's no error message?

The output of `[System.Environment]::OSVersion` is `Win32NT 10.0.14393.0`.

The dependencies from the project are:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens": "5.1.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR": "2.2.1",
    "Akka": "1.1.3",
    "Akka.Remote": "1.1.3"
},

"frameworks": {
    "net461": {
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Nano server does not support the Full .NET framework, you can only run netstandard apps, so this will not work.